# Chrome - multiple sessions in one window

Tags: google-chrome

By default, when there are multiple user profiles in Google Chrome, each profile's session is opened in a different window.

Is there a way to have the sessions of multiple profiles open in the same window with different tabs (like the way Firefox's [Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) works)?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: I _really_ want this feature. I was using SessionBox - and I've also been trying Firefox for Multi-Account Containers, too. I've starred this post on the Chrome forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/iJmPb7dusHc;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/profiles$20window if anyone else wants this feature, please do the same!